# At what temperature does flowing water start to freeze?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, phase-transition, ice, freezing

We know that flowing water remains liquid even in the below-zero temperatures (a good example is rivers in arctic regions). Of course water doesn't remain liquid forever if temperature goes down constantly. Also, I know water freezes from surface. But that's for stationary waters like lakes. Not for flowing waters like a dam output which is so fast.

I think it depends on a sort of things, like the speed of molecules, the viscosity of water, etc.

Can we formulate it to find the answer? Perhaps with such a formula we can find the freezing temperature of other flowing liquids as well.

And a minor question: How does the density of flowing water behave in below-zero temperatures?

Comment: The density of supercooled water decreases with increasing supercooling (near the freezing point), going from 0.9999 g/ml at 0C to 0.9775 g/ml at -34C.

Comment: Wow! But still the density is bigger than 0C ice.

Comment: Have you looked into the [stagnation temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stagnation_temperature)? Moving water contains kinetic energy that warms it if the water stops, acting against freezing.

Comment: Would you be satisfied by discussing the problem of water at temperature T>0C entering and flowing through a pipe, with the pipe wall maintained at T<0C?